# Watson Retrieve and Rank: Python Bluemix runtime

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, retrieve-and-rank

I am trying to run through the following tutorial on Bluemix:
https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/retrieve-rank/get_start.shtml

However, I am not able to install Python locally onto my system due to security policies. Is there a way I can run this tutorial through hosting my code in IBM DevOps Services using the Python runtime on Bluemix?

I am not sure if the Bluemix Python runtime can be leveraged like a natively installed Python and accept the command line instructions from:

**Stage 4: Create and train the ranker.**

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to the manual Python and curl commands in that tutorial is to use the web interface.

I've written about it in some detail [on my blog](http://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=3381) which also includes a [video walkthrough](https://youtu.be/SveIksv7V9E) of how the web tool works. (You can also find the [official documentation](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/retrieve-rank/ranker_tooling.shtml) on ibm.com).

But to sum up, it'd mean you could do everything through a web browser and not have to install or run anything locally - including training a ranker.

There is a small wrinkle in this plan right now, unfortunately. The Solr schema used in the Python/curl tutorial you've followed isn't compatible with the web tool, but [we're working on that](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/answers/286522/view.html). This means that if you use the web tool, you'll need to start again with a new cluster and collection. But this means that you could start again using your own documents, content and training questions, instead of having to use the cranfield test data - so hopefully this is a good thing!

Comment: Thanks! That is great news. I am also looking to potentially use a Docker container and/or Openstack VM image with Python preloaded to solve this security policy limitation as well.